# How to list files of a given extension in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to retrieve the list of direct files (i.e. no recursive search) of a given directory and a given extension in OCaml.

I tried the following but:

1. It does not look OCaml-spirit
2. It does not work (error of import)

```ml
let list_osc2 = 
  let list_files = Sys.readdir "tests/osc2/expected/pp" in
  List.filter (fun x -> Str.last_chars x 4 = ".osc2") (Array.to_list list_files)
```

I got the error (I am using OCamlPro):

```
Required module `Str' is unavailable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Filename.extension` instead of `Str.last_chars`:

```
let list_osc2 = 
  let list_files = Sys.readdir "tests/osc2/expected/pp" in
  List.filter (fun x -> Filename.extension x = ".osc2") (Array.to_list list_files)
```

and then use the pipe operator to make it a bit more readable:

```
let list_osc2 = 
  Sys.readdir "tests/osc2/expected/pp"
  |> Array.to_list
  |> List.filter (fun x -> Filename.extension x = "osc2")
```

I don't know how you expect this to work in OCamlPro though, as it doesn't have a filesystem as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `Str` module, you need to link with the [`str` library](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libstr.html). For example, with `ocamlc`, you need to pass `str.cma`, and with `ocamlopt`, you need to pass `str.cmxa`. I don't know how to do that with OcamlPro.

In any case, `Str.last_chars` is not particularly useful here. It doesn't work if the file name is shorter than the suffix. By the way, your code would never match because `".osc2"` is 5 characters, which is never equal to `last_chars x 4`.

The [`Filename` module](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/Filename.html) from the standard library has functions to extract and check a file's extension. You don't need to do any string manipulation.

I don't know what you consider “ugly as hell”, but apart from the mistake with string manipulation, I don't see any problem with your code. Enumerating the matches and filtering them is perfectly idiomatic.

```
let list_osc2 = 
  let list_files = Sys.readdir "tests/osc2/expected/pp" in
  List.filter (fun name -> check_suffix name ".osc2") (Array.to_list list_files)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Maybe I find it ugly because I'm still beginning with OCaml ;)